# Calling same controller's method using ajax GET and POST type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

Hi I am a newbie to Grails and Groovy. Please help me to solve the below issue related to calling controller's method using ajax call.
The scenario behind the code is to recover the password using the username whenever the user is unable to remember the password. I have explained the code flow in detail below.
Application begins with the below auth.gsp page:

```
<form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id='loginForm' autocomplete='off'>
    <input type='text' name='j_username' id='username'/>
    <input type='password' name='j_password' id='password'/>
    <input type='submit' id="submit" value='${message(code: "default.button.login")}'/>
    <a href="#" id="recovery-link" recovery-url="<g:createLink controller='recoverPassword' action='recoverPassword'/>"><g:message code="etranscripts.forgotPassword"/></a>
</form>
```

When I click on the Forgot password link of the anchor tag, it will call the below ajax method:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#recovery-link').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('recovery-url')

    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "html"
    }).done(function (html) {
    $('#loginForm').replaceWith(html)
    $('#sign-in-instruct').text('<g:message code="js.resetEnterName"/>')
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log("Request for url failed: " + url)
    })

    event.preventDefault()
    return false
    });
});
```

The controller method for the above call is as below.

```
def recoverPassword = {
    println "RecoverPassword method of ctrl....."
    if (!request.post) {
        // show the form
        render(template: "recoverPassword" )
        return
    }
//some other stuff based on the input conditions.
```

The successful output template for the above ajax call is:

```
<div id="recover-password" >
<ul>
    <li>
        <span><g:textField name="username" id="username" value="" /></span>
        <input type='submit' id="submit-username-link" recovery-url="<g:createLink controller='recoverPassword' action="recoverPassword"/>" value='Submit'/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Till here my code works perfect. But the issue begins from here. 
i.e When I enter some value in the username field of the template and click on submit, it should call the below ajax method.

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit-username-link', function (event) {

var url = $(this).attr('recovery-url')
var username = $('input#username').val();
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {username:username},
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function (responseJson) {
    $('#sign-in-instruct').text(responseJson.message)
    $('div.copyright').css('margin','74px 0px 0px 140px')
    $('#home-link').show()
    if ( responseJson.status == 'success') {
        $('#recover-password').remove()
    }
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    $('#recover-password').remove()
    $('#sign-in-instruct').text(textStatus)
    console.log("Failed to send the email " + textStatus)
})

event.preventDefault()
return false
});
```

The thing is, url refers to the same method of the controller but the only change is POST type is used and that will be taken into consideration inside the method using if conditions.(i.e some other stuff of the controller)
These GET and POST type of method calls are configured as shown below in the URLMappings.groovy file.

```
"/recoverPassword/recoverPassword"(controller: 'recoverPassword') {
        action = [GET: "recoverPassword", POST: "recoverPassword"]
    }
```

The whole summary of this question is, for the same method of controller, GET request is working but POST type of ajax call is not able to reach the controller's method.

Am I doing anything wrong over here? Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Take a look at and change from  `<input type='submit' id="submit-username-link" recovery-url=` to  how you have it on the first page `<a href="#" id="submit-username-link" recovery-url="`. When you create a `type="button"` within a form. What this does is trigger form click and submit a form. So it will totally disregard what you were trying to do which is to trigger the link. You can use anything even 'div' 'span' as long as style it like a button or link it will then trigger. This is a common problem when having alternative buttons in same form

Answer (score 0):

Overcomplicated. Why don't you use separate function in controller for GET (rendering the form) and separate function for POST (for handling the recovering the password)?

Check out also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: Hi Michal, I have tried the same, still it is not able to reach the controller. When I make it individual, even GET is also not working. By the way, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Probably you have made kind of mistake cause I'm using such an approach all the time and it's working. You should always distinguish render method from action method for simplicity and clearness of your code. Could you share your approach to look for an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change input Type submit to button

```
 <input type='button' id="submit-username-link" recovery-url="<g:createLink controller='recoverPassword' action="recoverPassword"/>" value='Submit'/>
```

Comment: Hi Sayem, thanks for the answer, unfortunately did not work :-(